# In open delta connection, when one transformer stops working, do the other 2 transformers give 2 phase current?

Tags: transformer

In open delta connection, when one transformer stops working, do the other 2 transformers give 2 phase current or 3 phase current (and why 3 phase current not 2 phase current?) and if so why can't we use back to back connection with it as it is more efficient?